# How to unprotect Excel sheets in Linux (Debian/Squeeze)

Tags: debian, spreadsheet

I have a fairly complex (by my standards) process that extracts Excel files (`.xls`) from certain inbound emails and saves them in a directory on my Debian/Squeeze machine.

My next step would have been to use `xls2csv` (`catdoc`) to convert the `.xls` files into `.csv`, before modifying it using regex and loading it into a database.

However, I just realized that each sheet in the `.xls` files is locked, preventing `xls2csv` from converting them into `.csv` format.

Is there a command/solution to **batch** unprotect the sheets in `.xls` files in a directory? (The idea is to unprotect them in-place, without opening them one at a time.)

Comment: I am not sure, but I am reasonably confident that you will have to open each file individually because the sheet locking is a worksheet property rather than a file level property.

Comment: Just a wild guess: LibreOffice has extensive internal APIs, perhaps there is a way of doing this?

Comment: @vonbrand Possibly. I will scour through the `LibreOffice` documentation. FYI, I also tried `pyexcelerator`, hoping that it might convert locked worksheets into `.csv`, but it didn't work.